# Unexpected behavior of HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in MySQL-

```
runs overs
 5     6
 6     7
```

I am trying to test the behavior of having clause without group by clause.

```
When i write-
select * from cricket having runs=MIN(runs);
OUTPUT-
runs overs
 5     6

select * from cricket having runs=MAX(runs);
OUTPUT-
Empty Set
```

What is the reason behind this behavior?

EDIT:
On reversing the row order-

```
runs overs
 6     7
 5     6
```

The output is as follows-

```
select * from cricket having runs=MIN(runs);
OUTPUT-
Empty Set

select * from cricket having runs=MAX(runs);
OUTPUT-
runs overs
 6     7
```

Comment: First query is not working either for me, causing a error due to non group by in MySQL

Comment: The MIN query works for me in MySQL

Comment: Amusingly if you reverse the row order the first query returns nothing.

Comment: I have edited the question and behavior after the reversing the row order is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using select, aggregation function and having clause in improper way  ..

could you are using a mysql version prrevious 5.7 so the behaviour is allowed  but with unpredictble result  .. (for mysql version > 5.6 by defualt this kind on query produce an error)

The preoper way for using aggreagtion function, having a and select columns is based on

the mention in group by clause of the columns not involved  in aggregation function

so you first query should be

```
select * 
    from cricket 
    having runs = ( 
        select min(runs) from cricket
    )
```

or

```
select c.* 
from cricket c
inner join  (
    select overs, min(runs) min_runs
    from cricket 
    group by  overs
    order by min_runs desc limit 1
) t on t.overs = c.overs 
    and t.min_runs = c.runs
```

Comment: Can you please give me more clarity on why your first query works? Why writing statements in this order gives the correct result?

Comment: because the use of  min(runs) without proper control using group by  (or a specific select as in my sample)  although it is allowed in the mysql version <5.7 it produces unpredictable results. usually the first value found is presented ,  (but not always),  for this reason starting from version 5.7 this type of syntax is no longer allowed by default and can be used at properio risk only by disabling the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY parameter